How can I make a box with rounded corners that have asymmetrical dimensions?
I have this command that makes colored boxes with the top-right corner cut.
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    
     \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red,size=small, arc is angular, sharp corners, rounded corners=northeast,
                arc=1.1\baselineskip, boxrule=0pt, width=5em,nobeforeafter]
            \noindent
            \raggedright
            \textbf{\textcolor{white}{MAIN\\MOUNT}}
        \end{tcolorbox}\hfill
    
    \end{document}

Which results in the corner making two 45° turns instead of one 90° turn. However, I want the corner to make a 30° turn and then a 60° turn. How do I do that?
[EDIT] Solved! Here is the final code of the command:
\newcommand{\mountbox}[3]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        colback=#1,
        size=small, 
        boxrule=0pt, 
        width=#3,
        nobeforeafter,
        sharp corners,
        coltext=white,
        fontupper=\bfseries,
        overlay={
            \filldraw[white] ([xshift=-0.24cm]frame.north east)  -- 
            (frame.north east) -- 
            ([yshift=-0.14cm]frame.north east) -- 
            cycle;
        }
    ]
    \textbf{\textcolor{white}{#2}}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \hfill
}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I edited the question as requested. I needed to take excerpts of both the .sty file and the .tex document, beacuse both are very long

That's not a compilable document. There is no class and your .sty file never gets loaded by the .tex file. All these unrelated packages aren't helpful, what would be helpful is a small, but compilable test document which we can copy & paste to reproduce your problem.

It's not a "problem" per se: I just want to know how to make boxes with rounded corners that look like I folded the corner at an angle of my choice. I know it's probably dead simple but I've never worked with Latex before.

The "problem" is that you have boxes with 45 degrees. If we want to show you how to get 30 degrees, a test file which allows us to reproduce the 45 degrees would be helpful.

Ok: I've put in a Google Drvie link to a .zip file with the template which anyone can just slot into overleaf.
Thanks for your patience.

Please don't. Links rot over time and then your question will not be useful for others. Make the document as small as possible and post it here. Remember replace any graphics with some that others have access to, say the ones from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe

@LucaBallanzeddu We neither need or want a large .zip file. Please make a small, but compilable test document.

Ok, I've reduced the template to the compile.py, FieldGuide.sty, latexmkrc, and Main.tex files, reduced the .sy and .tx files to only the relevant part, and pasted them here as codeblocks. I 'v renamed the images and fonts folders to check if the project compiles even if the image and fonts link go nowhere and it compiles, so you should be able to make this work.

This is technically possible because on the PGF layer we can use different radii for the rounded corners and they do work with \tcbpatharcangular but the arc key doesn't simply correspond to the rounded corners key.

Instead of using rounded corners, you could use an under- or overlay in the same colour as the background:
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,
  colback=red,
  size=small, 
  boxrule=0pt, 
  width=5.5em,
  nobeforeafter,
  sharp corners,
  coltext=white,
  fontupper=\bfseries,
  overlay={
    \filldraw[white] ([xshift=-0.6cm]frame.north east) -- ++(-30:0.7cm)  -- (frame.north east) -- cycle;
  }  
]
  MAIN \newline MOUNT
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}



This works! I just needed to adjust the values a tad.

The PGF version of rounded corners, the \pgfsetcornersarced command, actually allows two different radii and this also works with TCB's \tcbpatharcangular patch.
Implementing this in TCB directly is not trivial since it just doesn't simply forward the value of /tcb/arc to /tikz/rounded corners but does much more.
Here is an approach that patches and redefines some things so that it almost works the same. For some reason, I have to set both the outer arc and the normal arc.
If my math is correct, the ratio between the two radii must be tan(60°).
Code
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  rounded corners/.code=
    \pgfutil@in@{ and }{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@ \tikzset{rounded corners xy={#1}}%
    \else          \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{#1}{#1}}\fi,
  rounded corners xy/.code args={#1 and #2}{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{#1}{#2}}}}
\tcbset{
  both arcs/.style={arc={#1}, outer arc={#1}},
  arc/.code=
    \pgfutil@in@{ and }{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@ \tcb@setarcs{kvtcb@}#1\pgf@stop
    \else          \tcb@setarcs{kvtcb@}{#1} and {#1}\pgf@stop \fi,
  outer arc/.code=
    \pgfutil@in@{ and }{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@ \tcb@setarcs{tcb@outer@}#1\pgf@stop
    \else          \tcb@setarcs{tcb@outer@}{#1} and {#1}\pgf@stop \fi}
\def\tcb@setarcs#1#2 and #3\pgf@stop{%
    \expandafter\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\csname #1arc\endcsname{max(#2,#3)}%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1arcx\endcsname{#2}%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1arcy\endcsname{#3}}
\def\tcb@arc@ins{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{\kvtcb@arcx}{\kvtcb@arcy}}}%
\def\tcb@arc@out{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{\tcb@outer@arcx}{\tcb@outer@arcy}}}%
\let\tcb@arc@out@NW@rounded\tcb@arc@out\let\tcb@arc@out@NE@rounded\tcb@arc@out
\let\tcb@arc@out@SW@rounded\tcb@arc@out\let\tcb@arc@out@SE@rounded\tcb@arc@out
\let\tcb@arc@ins@NW@rounded\tcb@arc@ins\let\tcb@arc@ins@NE@rounded\tcb@arc@ins
\let\tcb@arc@ins@SW@rounded\tcb@arc@ins\let\tcb@arc@ins@SE@rounded\tcb@arc@ins
\tcbset{both arcs=+0pt}% default?
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tcbpatcharcangular
\draw[help lines] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0);
\draw[rounded corners=10pt and 5pt] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  colback=red, size=small, boxrule=0pt, width=5.5em, nobeforeafter,
  arc is angular, sharp corners, rounded corners=northeast,
  both arcs=1.732*5pt and +5pt]
\noindent\raggedright
\textbf{\textcolor{white}{MAIN\\MOUNT}}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

Output

